# Echo local ASP.NET url FROM PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, cross-language

I have a php wordpress site that's running on IIS. I need to include, as part of that file, the response from a local ASP.NET page. PHP is reallly not my strongest language though.

The code I have is:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']+'/GetDesigns.ashx?type=1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$localText = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $localText;
?>
```

Making a request to /GetDesigns.ashx?type=1 works from a browser and echos a string, but when the above code is used on the page, I get nothing.

Is there any way to do this or is it just me misusing PHP?

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

will give you a file path.

Use

```
"http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

or a hardcoded address instead.